# What's the position of the four major Sunni schools regarding female witnesses

Tags: fiqh, sunni, hanafi, shafii, maliki

1. What's the position of the four schools regarding Muslim women testifying in cases other than those being traditionally the domain of women (suckling, menstruation, idda, etc)? I want to know if they can testify at all.
2. What's the position of the four schools regarding Muslim women's testimony's worth compared to that of men? Is a woman's testimony invited only if two men are not available?
3. What's the position of the four schools regarding the number of Muslim women required for testifying in cases stated in point 1?

If possible, please give references from established fiqh books or academic writings. I intend to know the majority opinion of scholars in these schools, not the exceptional ones.